# Issue show MenuFlyout item in each appbar button Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have appbar buttons with flyout item inside each:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
<CommandBar>

    <!--app bar basic shape-->
    <AppBarButton x:Name="BaseShapeMenu" Label="Hình cơ bản">
        <AppBarButton.Icon>
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="▭"/>
        </AppBarButton.Icon>
        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'▭' Rectangle" Tag="stRectangle" Click="BaseShapeMFI_Click" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⬬' Ellipse" Tag="stEllipse" Click="BaseShapeMFI_Click" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'/' Line" Tag="stLine" Click="BaseShapeMFI_Click" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    </AppBarButton>

    <!--app bar chemical shape-->
    <AppBarButton x:Name="ChemicalShape" Label="Hình hóa học">
        <AppBarButton.Icon>
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="⌬"/>
        </AppBarButton.Icon>
        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⬡' CycloHexan"   Tag="stCycloHexan"   Click="ChemicalMFI_Click" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⌬' Benzen"       Tag="stBenzen"       Click="ChemicalMFI_Click" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⬣' BenzenCircle" Tag="stBenzenCircle" Click="ChemicalMFI_Click" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    </AppBarButton>

    <!--app bar symbol-->
    <AppBarButton x:Name="SymbolShape" Label="Ký tự">
        <AppBarButton.Icon>
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="♒"/>
        </AppBarButton.Icon>
        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⬡' CycloHexan"   Tag="stCycloHexan"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⌬' Benzen"       Tag="stBenzen"    />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="'⬣' BenzenCircle" Tag="stBenzenCircle"  />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
    </AppBarButton>

    <AppBarButton x:Name="SelectButton" Label="Chọn hình" Icon="Edit" Click="SelectButton_Click"/>

</CommandBar>
```

Menu Flyout items of each button are lost position. When run it show like as pictures below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone suggest any way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are Right its Windows 8.1 issue where the property of MenuFlyout is set on Top which causes the defect due to it lying on top of other flyouts.
The only solution that I found was adding additional blank MenuItems inside the flyouts

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1F1F1F" Opacity="0.4"/>
            </CommandBar.Background>

            <!--app bar basic shape-->
            <AppBarButton x:Name="BaseShapeMenu" Label="Hình cơ bản">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="▭"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout x:Name="Flyout_BaseShapeMenu">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_1" Text="'▭' Rectangle" Tag="stRectangle" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_2" Text="'⬬' Ellipse" Tag="stEllipse" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_3" Text="'/' Line" Tag="stLine" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>

            <!--app bar chemical shape-->
            <AppBarButton x:Name="ChemicalShape" Label="Hình hóa học">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="⌬"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout x:Name="Flyout_ChemicalShape">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_4" Text="'⬡' CycloHexan"   Tag="stCycloHexan" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_5" Text="'⌬' Benzen"       Tag="stBenzen" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_6" Text="'⬣' BenzenCircle" Tag="stBenzenCircle" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>

            <!--app bar symbol-->
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SymbolShape" Label="Ký tự" >
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="♒"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout x:Name="Flypu_SymbolShape">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_7" Text="'⬡' CycloHexan"   Tag="stCycloHexan"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_8" Text="'⌬' Benzen"       Tag="stBenzen"    />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="_9" Text="'⬣' BenzenCircle" Tag="stBenzenCircle"  />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton x:Name="SelectButton" Label="Chọn hình" Icon="Edit"/>

        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Please add back your click events and remove the naming as I was testing your code to give you a possible answer and had to delete them. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank for help, but don't any way solve that problem. I have to wait update's Microsoft for the issue, do not it ?

Comment: Again thank for answer. However, the answer don't satisfy my desired. I could be done like it ago, but I don't want to use this way that the code still run correctingly.